# Cannot access one particular model in Laravel, getting a BLANK page

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I am trying to get distinct city names from a MySQL table called "city".

Here is how the controller code looks like:

```
public function getCityNames()
{
    if(Auth::check()) 
    {
        $cities = DB::table('city')->distinct()->get();
        var_dump($cities);
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::route('account-signin');
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the model City:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class City extends Eloquent
{
    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'city';

    /**
     * Using a different primary key name
     *
     */
    protected $primaryKey  = 'geoname_id';  

    public $timestamps = false;
}
```

**The Problem**

I can output distinct values from other models using the exact code as in this controller above but when I run it for the city, I get a BLANK page.

- I am using Laravel 4 with detailed error messages enabled.
- Of course, there is data in the 'city' table

**UPDATE:**
When I write the following, I get data:

```
public function Test()
{
    return City::where('country_name', '=', 'Canada')->get();
}
```

But when I write the following, I get the black page? Something with the data size?

```
public function Test()
{
    return City::all()->get();
}
```

Comment: Did you return anything ? Your controller code is not using the `model`.

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha - I tried using the lists method on the model City. That's when I got the blank page. After trying to debug a bit, I came to the conclusion that my code is unable to use this model.

Comment: Show your exact code that is not working.

Comment: $cities = City::lists('city_name', 'geoname_id');

return View::make('settings.cities', array('cities' => $cities));

Comment: This should work if there are any record available.

Comment: Ya, I am confused too. I spent hours debugging. There is data.

Comment: Try `dd(DB::table('city')->get())` and see what you get.

Comment: still nothing. I will keep trying an update.

Comment: Just to check if the model is working properly, output `City::all();` and see if you can get the database models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to access the city table fine when I ran small queries (see my update in the question). Only explanation could be that I was exceeding the browser buffer size when I was trying to get all . This table has more than 70,000 rows.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is problem, but are you trying to view the output of `var_dump($cities)`?

If so, shouldn't `return var_dump($cities);` give you the output, rather than the empty page?

Code looks like this:

```
public function getCityNames()
{
    if(Auth::check()) // Tip: You can apply auth filters to controllers if you want. 
    {
        $cities = DB::table('city')->distinct()->get();
        return var_dump($cities); // Add return here.
    }
    else
    {
        return Redirect::route('account-signin');
    }

    // If the code doesn't go anywhere, it goes here.
    return "TEST";
}
```

Comment: Hi eluong, that's right, I am trying to view the output of var_dump($cities) and for some strange reason getting a blank page.

Comment: Try the code block I just put in the edit. This will check at least whether its a controller problem or a model problem.

Comment: Still blank. You're right about the Auth::check() ... I removed it as it was redundant. To see if my route is even getting hit, I put something like $var = "nuts";
  var_dump($var); in the controller above and I am getting string 'nuts' (length=4) ... so the route points to this controller correctly.

Comment: You're not even getting a null for var_dump($cities)? lol strange... Have you done a composer dump-autoload recently? I doubt that's an issue but it's nice to make sure your new classes are in the application.

Comment: I deleted the model and I got an error as expected. I re-added the model and getting this error "Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'City' not found" ... something I am missing here?  --- NVM, I saved an existing model and City. Forgot to rename the class. Now back to a blank page. I just did a composer dump-autoload, which pointed the above error.

Comment: Warning: Ambiguous class resolution, "UserDetail" was found in both "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp-mvc/app/models/City.php" and "/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/myapp-mvc/app/models/UserDetail.php", the first will be used.  (this was the output)

Comment: Try removing `use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;` and `use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;` from the model and see what happens.

Comment: LOL ... still blank. The geoname_id which is my primary key in the 'city' table is a third-party unique identifier for cities. It's not an incremental primary key. Could that be a problem?

Comment: No that should be fine as long as the foreign key exists on another table (Laravel migration wouldn't let you create the table otherwise). Try `return var_dump(City::all());` in your controller and see if you can retrieve the model.

Comment: Thought so... I will rebuilt this table and see if that makes any difference. No way to share a screenshot here. Otherwise, I would have shown that the city has data. This is just weird.

Comment: Still no luck. Thanks for trying @eluong. I will update this post once I figure out the problem.